# Can't login with real password in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've a registration form as well as login form. I've used md5 encryption in my registration form and it's working fine. But when I'm trying to login with real password like (123) it's not logging me in. On the other hand, when I copy paste that md5 encryption in password field, it's then logging me in. Please help me about this! Thank you!

Here is my coding:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $user_name = $_POST['username'];
            $user_email = $_POST['email'];
            $user_pass = $_POST['password'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users where Email = '" . $_POST["email"] . "'";
            $result = $obj->run_query($query);

            if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

                $query = "INSERT INTO users (Name,Email,Pass) VALUES ('$user_name','$user_email', md5('$user_pass'))";
                $result = $obj->run_query($query);

                echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Registered!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

            } else {

                echo "<script>alert('This user email $user_email is already exist!')</script>";
            }
        }

    // login script
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email' AND Pass = '$password'";
        $result = $obj->run_query($query);

        if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";



        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Your email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: `$password = md5($_POST['pass']);` and make sure that password column's length is 32+. However, if this is intended for, or is a live site; *STOP right there*. Edit: and use v_v_v

Comment: `md5` is not an encryption! You should be using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` or a similar strong method. See [this q&a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) for much more information on PHP and passwords

Comment: Plus, no way of telling what's in the HTML form.

Comment: and you should secure your queries against sql-injection

Comment: *"On the other hand, when I copy paste that md5 encryption in password field, it's then logging me in."* - As I stated [*up there...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706844/cant-login-with-real-password-in-php#comment59090355_35706844) and you never inserted it into DB as a hash to start off with.

Comment: You never hashed the password entered into the login form, so you're comparing `hunter42 == md5('hunter42')` which will never be equal. And you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so your login system is essentially useless. try `' or 1=1` as your password...

Comment: SQL Injection and [Little Bobby Tables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked for me! :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're welcome @AishaSalman

Comment: Thank you all for your help! :)

Comment: @AishaSalman curious though: You're not "live" with this, are you? or wanting to go live?

Comment: No it's not live yet! actually it's my final year project and I'm a newbie in PHP and MYSQL @Fred-ii-

Comment: *"not live yet"*. Don't ever go live with this. See the answer I've given you below.

Comment: @AishaSalman I feel that you/your school may also be victims of not being taught what's going on in the "real world" of databases/password storage. I see many questions where people say that the schools don't teach them about security issues. It's really a shame that that is what is happening today, especially in this day and age. Stack is a good place to read up on Q&A's in relation to this. I for one, have learned most of what I know on Stack, including Google/other websites. *Stay safe*, cheers.

Comment: Totally agree with you and yes I also learnt so much from Stack :) @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated: you're comparing plain text from the POST array `$password = $_POST['pass'];` to the MD5 in your table.

That should read as `$password = md5($_POST['pass']);`

I also stated that you shouldn't go live with this, ***"ever"***. If it is a live site, I suggest you put it on hold until you use a safe hashing function that is of "this century".

MD5 is 30+ years old and is no longer considered safe to use now to hash/store passwords with.

Consult the following:

- [Is MD5 considered insecure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

**Passwords**

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

---

Your present code is also open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Hi! :) can you please guide me how can I replace this md5 hashing with password_hash() in my coding? I've tried to implement this in my coding but no use. And also my php version is 5.6.15 @Fred-ii-

Comment: @AishaSalman Hi. I just saw you got a solution for it http://stackoverflow.com/q/35721035/ but noticed that you originally accepted Mark's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35722556/ but chose the other one instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/35721231/ - any reason? I was "mobile" at the time I saw this, and very limited to do things on that.