# password_hash() not working

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please guide me where I'm doing mistake. Password hashing is working fine and gets stored in my database but when I'm try to login using real password like (123), it's not logging me in. Thank you!

```
    <?php
        // registration script
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $user_name = $_POST['username'];
            $user_email = $_POST['email'];
            $user_pass = $_POST['password'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users where Email = '" . $_POST["email"] . "'";
            $result = $obj->run_query($query);

            if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

                $query = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Email, Pass) VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_email . "', '" . password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . "')";
                $result = $obj->run_query($query);

                echo "<script>alert('You have successfully Registered!')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

            } else {

                echo "<script>alert('This user email $user_email is already exist!')</script>";
            }
        }

    // login script
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email' AND Pass = '$password'";
        $result = $obj->run_query($query);

        if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";

        } else 

        {
            echo "<script>alert('Your email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: There is no mention of `password_hash()` anywhere in your code and saying somethng is "giving errors" without telling us the errors is useless. Also read up on SQL Injection attacks and prevention of it.

Comment: The [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function is used to compare a user-input plaintext password with the stored, hashed password, exactly as described in the PHP Docs..... you don't hash the user eneterd password and compare the hashes, that simply cannot work as password_hash() uniquely salts the value every time it is called

Comment: So your login check code should be retrieving the record from the `users` table using just the Email address, and then using password_verify to compare the user-entered password with the password hash retrieved by that SQL query

Comment: Can you please correct my code as I don't understand this way? @MarkBaker

Comment: @AishaSalman You need to use `password_verify`. Every time you call `password_hash` a *new, unique* hash is generated. The start of this hash includes the salt that is being used, and this salt will be unique every time, hence resulting in a different hash. You have to select the user by username and *then, in PHP* check the password hash. By the way, your code is riddled with SQL injection. Please prepare your statements and bind your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to correct the SQL injection issues yourself, this is simply to demonstrate how to use `password_verify()`

```
// login script
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];


    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = '$email'";
    $result = $obj->run_query($query);

    if ($count = mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_object();
        if (password_verify($password, $row->Pass)) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

            echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Your email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Your email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! you solved my problem :) @Mark Baker

Comment: @AishaSalman As I mentioned, keep in mind that your script is open to SQL injection. I could easily try to log in with every single user without knowing their emails just by using the "email" `' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 0, 1 --` for the first user, `' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1, 1 --` for the second user etc.

Comment: ok got it! thanks @h2ooooooo

Answer (score 1):

This CAN'T work:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (Name,Email,Pass) VALUES ('$user_name','$user_email', md5('$user_pass'))";
```

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Email, Pass) VALUES('" . $user_name . "', '" . $user_email . "', '" . password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT) . "')";
```

password_hash function is giving you a hash crypted with the BCRYPT algorithm. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

This is pretty vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read yourself in on how to prevent them. Search for 'parameterized queries'!

Comment: Hey I did the same but then it's not logging me in :/ @Ferhat Sayan

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Can you please correct my code as I don't know how to implement this in my coding? @Ferhat Sayan